# Ajax section not working correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get the ajax section to work but I have had no luck.  I tried putting it in a different section but the variable "selection" does not go through and the page does not update.  Basically what I"m trying to do is get the a value entered in the dropdown input item and then using that value to create a table in the Ajax function.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.css"> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/git/jquery.mobile-git.js"></script> 

<script>

    $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
        $( "#mylist li" ).on( "click", function() {
            $( "#myinput" ).val( $( this ).text() );  
            $("#mylist li" ).addClass('ui-screen-hidden');

            var selection = $( "#myinput" ).val(); 
            var station_code = "null";

            if (selection == "Location1")
            {
                station_code = "A254"; 
                my_url="www.someurl.com/"+station_code;
            }
            else{
                station_code = "A300";
            }

            $.ajax({
                 type:"get",    
                 dataType: 'jsonp',
                 url: "www.someurl.com",
                success: function(data) {
                    //write code
                }
            });

        });
    });

</script> 

<div data-role="content" id="content">
<form class="ui-filterable">
    <input type="text" id="myinput">
</form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-input="#myinput" id="mylist">
    <li>location1</li>
    <li>location2</li>
    <li>location3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What's an AJAX section?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `document.write()`.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console? That code looks syntactically incorrect to me (that stray `else` in particular).

Comment: Where does this `else` com from? You closed the `if` before.

Comment: No salvage for this one I'm afraid. Not even signs of basic programming skills in place.

Answer (score 1):

I think your javascript code is a bit messy. Try this one :

```
   $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
        $( "#mylist li" ).on( "click", function() {
            $( "#myinput" ).val( $( this ).text() );  
            $("#mylist li" ).addClass('ui-screen-hidden');

            var selection = $( "#myinput" ).val(); 
            var location_code = "null";
            var my_url = "null";

            if (selection == "Elm St"){
                 location_code = "R227";
             }

            my_url="www.somelink.com";            

            $.ajax({        
                type: "post",
                url: my_url,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(data){        
                    document.write(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    document.write ("didn't work");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: thank you for the response.  My apologies for the messy code.  I copied the code correct code but somehow when it got screwed up after I pasted it.  I did try your suggestion but it's not working.  I'm going to try something else later on but right now I need some sleep.  I'll let you know if I get it to work.  Thanks again for your help =)